# Find the value of $\lim_{ n \to \infty} \left(\frac{1^2+1}{1-n^3}+\frac{2^2+2}{2-n^3}+\frac{3^2+3}{3-n^3}+...+\frac{n^2+n}{n-n^3}\right)$

Tags: limits, definite-integrals

The following question is taken from the practice set of JEE Main exam.

> Find the value of $$\lim_{ n \to \infty} \left(\frac{1^2+1}{1-n^3}+\frac{2^2+2}{2-n^3}+\frac{3^2+3}{3-n^3}+...+\frac{n^2+n}{n-n^3}\right)$$

I wrote it as$$\lim_{ n \to \infty} \sum_{r=1}^n\frac{r^2+r}{r-n^3}\\=\lim_{ n \to \infty} \sum_{r=1}^n\frac{r(r+1)}{r-n^3}\\=\lim_{ n \to \infty} \sum_{r=1}^n\frac{r(\dfrac rn+\dfrac1n)}{\dfrac rn-n^2}\\=\lim_{ n \to \infty} \sum_{r=1}^n\frac{\dfrac rn(\dfrac rn+\dfrac1n)n}{\dfrac rn-n^2}$$

To convert it into into integration, $\dfrac rn$ can be written as $x$. $\dfrac1n$ is written as $dx$, but instead we have $n$. How to tackle that? Or any other approach for the question? Just a hint would suffice. Thanks.

Comment: Should the third formula be $\displaystyle \lim_{ n \to \infty} \sum_{r=1}^n\frac{r(\dfrac rn+\dfrac 1n)}{\dfrac rn-n^2}$ ?

Comment: You can ignore any terms that come out to things like $\frac{k}{n^2}$, $\frac{k}{n^3}$, or higher because their contribution will vanish more rapidly than the leading order contributions. This will simplify to $\sum -\frac{k^2}{n^2}\cdot\frac{1}{n} \to \int_0^1 -x^2dx$. You can prove this with squeeze theorem.

Comment: @TitoEliatron Thankyou, I assure you that was just a typo.

Comment: @NinadMunshi If I further divide numerator and denominator by $n^2$, I get $$\lim_{ n \to \infty} \sum_{r=1}^n\frac{\dfrac rn(\dfrac r{n^2}+\dfrac1{n^2})}{\dfrac r{n^3}-1}$$ So, here, $\dfrac r{n^3}$ and $\dfrac1{n^2}$ would be ignored? So, yes, that's indeed giving me $$\int_0^1-x^2dx$$ So, the answer is $-\dfrac13$. Thankyou.

Comment: @NinadMunshi While two beautiful answers have already been posted, any chance you could post your comment as answer? I'll accept it. Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

$R=\lim_{ n \to \infty} \left(\frac{1^2+1}{-n^3}+\frac{2^2+2}{-n^3}+\frac{3^2+3}{-n^3}+...+\frac{n^2+n}{-n^3}\right)=\lim_{ n \to \infty} \left(\frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)+3n(n+1)}{-6n^3}\right)=\frac{-1}{3}$

$P=\lim_{ n \to \infty} \left(\frac{1^2+1}{n-n^3}+\frac{2^2+2}{n-n^3}+\frac{3^2+3}{n-n^3}+...+\frac{n^2+n}{n-n^3}\right)=\lim_{ n \to \infty} \left(\frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)+3n(n+1)}{6(n-n^3)}\right)=\frac{-1}{3}$

$$R\ge\lim_{ n \to \infty} \left(\frac{1^2+1}{1-n^3}+\frac{2^2+2}{2-n^3}+\frac{3^2+3}{3-n^3}+...+\frac{n^2+n}{n-n^3}\right)\ge P$$

So $~\lim_{ n \to \infty} \left(\frac{1^2+1}{1-n^3}+\frac{2^2+2}{2-n^3}+\frac{3^2+3}{3-n^3}+...+\frac{n^2+n}{n-n^3}\right)=\frac{-1}{3}$

Comment: Nice answer, congratulations !

Answer (score 5):

Hint: $k-n^{3}$ lies between $1-n^{3}$ and $n-n^{3}$ for $1 \leq k \leq n$. This allows you to show that $\lim \sup$ and $\lim \inf$ are both equal to $-\frac  1 3$ using the formulas for $\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n} k$ and $\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n} k^{2}$.